# Count the occurrence per nested list in another list in Python

Tags: python, list, count, nested-lists, find-occurrences

I am struggling with getting the output that I want. I have two lists as illustrated below:

```
h3_FP_DB = [['KE', 'EH', 'LA'], ['KE', 'EH'], ['KE'], ['EH'], ['KE', 'EH']]

h3_FP = [['KE'], ['KE', 'LA'], ['KE', 'EH', 'LA'],  ['KE', 'EH'], ['LA'], ['LA', 'EH'], ['EH']]
```

I would like to know the occurrence for every nested lists in h3_FP in the list h3_FP_DB. So using the example above my desired output would give the counts below. I don not know which type/structure is beneficial:

```
KE: 4
KE, LA: 1
KE, EH, LA: 1
KE, EH: 3
LA: 4
LA, EH: 1
EH: 4
```

Using the code in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-count-frequency-of-sublist-in-given-list/) example I made the following code:

```
h3_FP_Occurence = []

for i in range(len(h3_FP)):
  count = len([i for idx in range(len(h3_DB_FP)) if h3_DB_FP[idx : idx + len(i)] == i])
  h3_DB_FP.append(count)
```

This gives me the following error

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I have looked extensively in Stack overflow and the web but I couldn't find anything. Any idea on how I can count the occurrences of the nested lists in the main list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary/list comprehension to check whether each value in each list in `h3_FP` is in each list in `h3_FP_DB`, outputting the results into a list of dictionaries:

```py
h3_FP_Occurence = [{ ', '.join(l): sum(all(v in hl for v in l) for hl in h3_FP_DB) } for l in h3_FP]
```

Output:

```py
[
 {'KE': 4},
 {'KE, LA': 1},
 {'KE, EH, LA': 1},
 {'KE, EH': 3},
 {'LA': 1},
 {'LA, EH': 1},
 {'EH': 4}
]
```